# Merge specific changes from a branch from a commit to master

Tags: git, version-control, branch, git-branch, branching-and-merging

If I have a branch and have commited changes in 2 files.
If I decide to merge the branch but with only the changes of one file, how would I do this in `git`?
Or should I manually do the changes in `master` branch?

Comment: Are your changes part of a single commit?  Or do you have multiple commits?

Comment: @CarlNorum:They are part of a single commit in the separate branch

Comment: @Jim is it your most recent commit?  Are there other commits in between?

Comment: @jszakmeister:The most recent commit

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways you could do that. Since you want to apply just a partial commit, pure merge is probably not the best way. The simplest way, I would think of is, to checkout the file from the commit of the other branch and commit it in the current branch:

```
git checkout <commit> <path to file>
git add <path to file>
git commit
```

Be aware that this will effectively **overwrite** the file in your current branch / working copy with the one from the other branch. So no merge is done!

Another possible solution would be to checkout the branch where you want the change to be applied, then cherry-pick the single commit from the other branch into your working copy and index and remove the file from index that should **not** be commited, i.e.:

```
git checkout <branch>
git cherry-pick --no-commit <hash of commit>
git reset HEAD <file which should not be commited>
# resolve any conflicts
git commit
```

This is more complex, but it merges the other file(s) into your current branch.

Answer (score 0):

Merge the branch as usual, and amend the last commit unselecting the changes of the target file. Alternatively ask merge to stop before commit, and stage only the desired file.

Using `git gui` it is pretty trivial.

Don't forget to note in merge commit what you did.

```
git merge mybranch
git gui
```

select the Amend last commit button and click on the unwanted file's icon in in the staged panel. Rewrite the message and hit commit.

If you want just a new commit without showing the merge in history, do the same, just start with

```
git merge --squash mybranch
```

Comment: I have no idea how to do any of your suggestions! :(

Comment: just do them in order. `git merge mybranch` then `git gui`, select the Amend last commit button and click on the unwanted file's icon in in the staged panel. Rewrite the message and hit commit

Comment: @BalogPal why not fix it up on the branch first?  That's more the "git" way.

Comment: @jszakmeister: I see no indication that the branch is not ok, sometimes I do partial or fake merges, especially after branching off a release